# How to sign and archive Xcode bundle that includes app extension for a custom keyboard

Tags: keyboard, ios8, xcode6, archive, sign

I built an app with a custom keyboard utilising new extensions in iOS8. This is using Objective C and Xcode6.

I tried to archive the bundle over and over in order to submit the bundle but without success. Anyone expert on the topic that can give a walkthrough to signing and archiving a bundle with extensions (keyboard extension)?

Many thanks in advance.